# How can I find out how many emails were sent during a specific period?

Tags: gmail

I would like to know how many email were sent from my account during certain period.
How can I know that?

The reason why I have to figure out it is that I need to prove the # of email I sent during that period.

The accused claims that I deleted emails which is important for the case.
I have to prove I didn't delete any email during that period.

I requested the data analysis to Gmail, Google but they didn't answer anything right now. 
Please let me know any possible method that I can prove.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `after:` and `before:` operators to search for messages within a date range. Combine with `from:` to specify that you want only messages *you* have sent.
Also, throw in a `in:anywhere` if you want to include messages in the *Spam* and *Trash* folders.

So something like:

```
after:2004/04/16 before:2005/06/01 in:anywhere from:youremailaddress@gmail.com
```

However, this will not let you prove that you have not deleted any messages during that period, only that you have actually sent something.

See [the documentation for Gmail search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).